# lumen 5.7 - how to get UNIX timestamp an integer format date records with where condition

Tags: laravel, lumen

working on very old existing database, there are records are stored with **UNIX timestamp an integer format** like below structure

```
id | name | email          | datetime
---------------------------------------
1  | abc  | abc@example.com | 1277812531

2  | xyz  | xyz@example.com | 1277862176

3  | pqr  | pqr@example.com | 1277926058

4  | wxy  | wxy@example.com | 1278348102

5  | nnn  | nnn@example.com | 1278381032
```

Now, I want to lumen query if **datetime is equals to pass by argument** to get records

The project use lumen 5.7, and one of the main problems is, that the database store the timestamp as UNIX timestamp in an integer column and not as timestamp column. And I'm searching for the best way to handle this.

Comment: You can define a getter to retrieve Unix as date. You can transform user input to Unix before query.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DB](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries) raw query and it works fine

```
$response = Model::where(\DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime), "%Y-%m-%d")'), '=', $_search_date)->get();
```

this is works for me :)